# Getting declaration or statement expected at the componentdidmount event

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to write componentDidMount in the following way, but its giving me compile error, can't I write that event const components?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../assets/js/CommonFunctions.js'

const AccessData = (props) => (

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:26854/api/premiershipteams")
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                let teamsFromApi = data.map(team => { return { value: team, display: team } })
                this.setState({ teams: [{ value: '', display: '(Select your favourite team)' }].concat(teamsFromApi) });
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
}

    <main>
        <div className="aqview-header">
            <div className="container about">
                <div className="header-tab">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <div className="text-wrap">
                                <h1>Access Data</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="container">
            <div className="aqview-section">
```

Any suggestion or help please thanks in advance

Comment: You're using `componentDidMount` in a functional component... You really should read the docs

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use `componentDidMount` in a functional component. The proper way is to use **Effect Hook** instead.

Let me share the below explanation from documentation:

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

The below example also from documentation:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
    useEffect(() => {
        // Update the document title using the browser API
        document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
    });

    return (
        <div>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
            Click me
        </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So in summary you can fetch data by using `useEffect` hook in your code. Read further about how to use the **Effect Hook** [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `componentDidMount` in a functional component. Use `useEffect` and pass an empty array to its dependencies, so it will work as a componentDidUpdate. For example:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:26854/api/premiershipteams")
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                let teamsFromApi = data.map(team => { return { value: team, display: team } })
                this.setState({ teams: [{ value: '', display: '(Select your favourite team)' }].concat(teamsFromApi) });
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
}, []);
```

You can either turn your functional component into a class component, or read a little on react hooks in the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).